# Many to Many Relationchip Query

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following query:

```
var users_t = context.Users.Select(x => 
  new {
    Username = x.Username,
    Roles = x.Roles.Select(y => y.Id).ToList()
  }
);
```

But I get the following error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Can this be solved? Maybe using SelectMany?

Could someone, please, help me out?

Thank you, Miguel

Comment: Just remove the .ToList()

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entities should be able to convert your expressions to SQL, and there's no SQL function for `.ToList()`. Try removing the `.ToList()`

```
var users_t = context.Users.Select(x => 
  new {
    Username = x.Username,
    Roles = x.Roles.Select(y => y.Id)
  }
);
```